# Representing a symmetric function in elementary symmetric functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

I'm trying to represent the following in the elementary symmetric functions base:

$ \sum\limits_{i \neq j} x^2_i x_j $

and

$ \sum\limits_{i \neq j} x_i^2 x_j^2 $

I don't really know how to algorithmically approach the problem. All I've managed so far was doing some guessing, but it has done no good

Comment: The first of these is pretty easy, isn't it?  Think "complete the square".

Comment: What, according to your definition, are the elementary symmetric functions? I ask, because the first of yours seems to be one already according to the definition I know.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake typing. Now it's correct. My definition is the same as the one in Wikipedia

Comment: OK so now the problem is rather different from the original.

Comment: The first is a cubic. With the elementary symmetric polynomials you can build the following cubic forms: $\sigma_1^3$, $\sigma_1\sigma_2$, $\sigma_3$. You can't use the first, because it produces pure cubes $x_i^3$ that cannot be cancelled by the others. So it has to be a linear combination of $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$. When you expand the product $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ it will produce the desired terms but also others. That's why you need $\sigma_3$. Leaving the details for you (or somebody else) as well as expanding this to an algorithm (IIRC Jacobson's Basic Algebra I describes one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, the first has degree $3$. So you need a linear combination of things of degree $3$. Note also that there are no terms involving cubes.

A degree three symmetric problem can always be solved by reference to the same problem with just three variables (this picks out the relevant terms, and if you go to four or more variables you only get terms of the same type, and the coefficients work out right).

The forms you have to work with are $(x+y+z)^3$, $(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$ and $xyz$. The first has cubic terms which can't be cancelled by the other forms. From there it is pretty easy.

For the second one, of degree $4$, it is more complex - you need four variables, and there are more possibilities. But note that there are no fourth powers, and no cubes, which reduces the possibilities once again to manageable proportions.